# How to test the version of Mysql ODBC driver programmatically

Tags: mysql, vbscript, odbc

I am connection to mysql using asp (vbscript) but I don't know the version of ODBC driver. I have no access to server administration and windows registry so:

1- I want to find the version of ODBC programmatically (or possibly through a sql command in phpmyadmin?).

2- However as a possible solution, I think looping through various connection strings may helps. How can I pass errors and find the suitable connection string? is there any callback or False/True return from connection strings?

possible connection strings:

```
    set objcon = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Connection")    
    objcon.connectionstring = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2 UNICODE Driver};Server=****;Database=****;User=****;Password=****;Option=3;"
    objcon.connectionstring = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=****;Database=****;User=****;Password=****;Option=3;"
    objcon.connectionstring = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Server=****;Database=2558_academy;User=****;Password=****;Option=3;"
```

Comment: Have you already tried the solution w/ registry thru winmgmt? To my knowledge, that doesn't require privilege escalation and only requires read only rights to the registry.

Answer (score 1):

```
set filepath=%~f1
set  file=%filepath:\=\\%
wmic datafile where name^="%file%" get version|findstr /i /v /c:"version"
echo %errorlevel%
```

A batch file using WMI, which any COM language can use. Pass the driver file as a parameter to the batch file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to connect to a MySQL database without exact knowledge wrt installed drivers you should loop over a list of possible connection strings and try them until the first of them succeeds.

Having an open connection you can either parse the connection string or use suitable properties of the connection.

In code:

```
   Dim oCnct : Set oCnct = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
  Dim sDrv
  For Each sDrv In Split("Complete nonsense|MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver|MySQL ODBC 9.9 Driver", "|")
      WScript.Echo sDrv
     On Error Resume Next
      oCnct.Open Replace("Driver={§};Server=gent;Database=pi;User=pa;Password=po;Option=3;", "§", sDrv)
      If 0 = Err.Number Then
         Exit For
      Else
         WScript.Echo "Error:", Err.Description
      End If
     On Error Goto 0
  Next
  If oCnct.State = adStateOpen Then
     WScript.Echo "Connected to MySQL using", sDrv
     Dim sProp
     For Each sProp In Split("Driver Version|Driver ODBC Version", "|")
         WScript.Echo oCnct.Properties(sProp).Name & ":", oCnct.Properties(sProp).Value
     Next
     oCnct.Close
  Else
     WScript.Echo "Failed to connected to MySQL"
  End If
```

output:

```
Complete nonsense
Error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver
Connected to MySQL using MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver
Driver Version: 05.01.0005
Driver ODBC Version: 03.51
```

Answer (score 0):

While you might not be able to open the registry, you may be able to query thru the winmgmts service. You can modify to your liking... let me know if it works. Otherwise there might be

```
for each key in split("SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ODBC Drivers,x86|SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ODBC\ODBCINST.INI\ODBC Drivers,x64", "|")
    strKeyPath=split(key, ",")(0)
    arch=split(key, ",")(1)
    Set objRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\default:StdRegProv")
    objRegistry.EnumValues &H80000002, strKeyPath, arrValueNames, arrValueTypes
    For i = 0 to UBound(arrValueNames)
        strValueName = arrValueNames(i)
        objRegistry.GetStringValue &H80000002,strKeyPath,strValueName,strValue
        Wscript.Echo "[" & arch & "] "& strValue & " " & arrValueNames(i) 
    Next
Next
```

It might be easier to also programmatically detect if you gave more info about the install for the connector itself in the file system.

```
C:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe - GUI tool for seeing the drivers
cd /d "C:\Program Files"
dir /s /b *odbc*dll | find /I "MySQL"
```

Once you find the correct odbc dlls for MySQL, you can usually scrape the driver version from the top line of the readme.txt file in the folder path.